# React Router works only after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am a bit new to react and I am facing a problem with the Router.
The routing works when I enter the URL directly on the browser, however when I click on the link, the URL changes on the browser (e.g http://localhost:8080/contactus), but the content don't get updated (But if I do a refresh, it gets updated).

Here is my github repo:
https://github.com/Arefaat18/Project

Here is my MainComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {TransitionGroup, CSSTransition} from 'react-transition-group';
import {Switch, Route, Redirect,withRouter,BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './HeaderComponent';
import ContactUs from './ContactUsComponent';
import AboutUs from './AboutUsComponent';
import Home from './HomeComponent.js';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';  

class Main extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  
  
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
        <Header />
        <TransitionGroup>
          <CSSTransition classNames="page" timeout={300}>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
              <Route exact path = "/contactus" component ={ContactUs} />
              <Route exact path = "/aboutus" component ={AboutUs} />
              <Redirect to="/home" />
            </Switch>
          </CSSTransition>
        </TransitionGroup>
        </Router>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Main);
```

And here is my App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Main from './components/MainComponent';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {ConfigureStore} from './components/configureStore';

const store = ConfigureStore();

class App extends Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="App">
            <Main />
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and here is the relevant dependancies

```
"react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-redux-form": "^1.16.14",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.4",
```

And here is my ContactUsComponent, the other components are just the same with different text

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ContactUs extends Component {

    render(){
        console.log("RENDER");
        return (
            <div>
                <h1> Contact Us</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ContactUs;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your routes are wrapped in 2 routers, one in the app file and another in the component file, you only need 1. Also, you just give the actual app as the component value for a route, i.e. `component={Home}`, you don't need that inline rendering. You've wrapped the component one with `withRouter`, if you `console.log` in the render function, is it re-rendering when you change route on the front end?

Comment: @Jayce444 I tried deleting the router wrapper in MainComponent.js but it's still the same result. If I leave it and delete the wrapper in App.js it gets an error  " Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(Main) /> outside a <Router>
 ".. I put the console.log as you suggested and it prints only when I refresh the page, not when I just click on the tab

Comment: Is this issue only with the "/contactus" path? All paths? Have you implemented any sort of page component memoization? Can you provide your component code as well? Is it possible to provide an exact set of reproduction steps, exactly what you are doing to see the issue? Can you create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue? Other than the fact that you can simply pass the component to the `component` prop I don't see anything overtly wrong here.

Comment: @DrewReese No the issue is with all the components. I haven't implemented Page Component memoization I don't really know about it. I edited my code to include my component. I also edited it to pass the component directly without inline styling.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce as much of your code into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-works-only-after-refreshing-the-page-gjkp8?file=/src/App.js) and it appears to work as I'd expect. Can you try creating a *running* codesandbox of your own that reproduces your issue? If your project is hosted in github you can directly import into a codesandbox.

Comment: @DrewReese I'll edit the post now to contain my github repo. But I get an error "API rate limit exceeded for app ID c07a89833b557afc7be2" when I open it in codesandbox. I noticed that the codesandbox you made was different in the HeaderComponent. Do you think the error may be from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, you've extraneous `Router`s declared, your header component has one. Remove this `Router`.

It is because each `Router` provides a routing context, and each component subscribing to *a* routing context gets the context from the closest router. The router providing context to the header wasn't rendering any routes so that is why the URL would change but the router *actually* rendering the `Route`s wasn't being notified that it should render a different path.

```
class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    ...
  }

  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {/* <Router> */} // <-- Remove this Router Component
        <Navbar dark expand="md">
          ...
        </Navbar>
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen} toggle={this.toggleModal}>
          ...
        </Modal>
        {/* </Router> */}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-works-only-after-refreshing-the-page]

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now! Can you explain why that produced the error?

Comment: @AhmedRefaat Well, it wasn't an error, per se, but I think it is because each `Router` provides a routing context, and each component subscribing to *a* routing context gets the context from the closest router. The router providing context to the header wasn't rendering any routes so that is why the URL would change but the router *actually* rendering the `Route`s wasn't being notified that it should render a different path. Amended answer.

Answer (score 6):

Well I also stuck with the same Issue but in react 18 our  component in index.js file is  by default wrapped in react strict mode

like this:

```
<React.StrictMode>
<App/>
</React.StrictMode>
```

I removed React strict Mode tags then it worked perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem. I used `Link` in the components, but I imported it from `@reach/router`.
As a result, I replaced

```
import { Link } from "@reach/router"
```

with

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
```

in each component; and everything worked as it should

Answer (score 0):

I just finish the course Front-End Web Development with React. I think you are learning this course too so I see nothing wrong with your code, possibly the problem is inside your ContactUs component. If you can provide your ContactUs code then I can debug it

Comment: I actually finished that course and it was working correctly, but I copied the router part into my new project and it produced the error. I edited my post with the ContactUsComponent. The error occurs with all the other components as well which are just the same but with the different <h2> text

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as well but I had to wrap my `App.js` with `BrowseRouter` in the `index.js` file.

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine with react v17 and react-scripts v4 but in react v18 that uses react-scripts v5 had the same issue. I removed the React.StrictMode tags inside of index.js
and that worked for me:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```